# How do I document dots (...) for generic functions when its usage differs between methods?

Tags: r

I have a generic function called `howmany(x, ...)` which returns the number of unique values in a dataframe, table, or vector. `x` contains the object, and the meaning of `...` changes depending on the method being called, e.g. selecting columns from the dataframe.

I currently have all of these described in a single Help doc (examples removed for brevity):

## Main document:

```r
#' Count the number of unique values
#'
#' @param x (Object) The object to count.
#'
#' @export
howmany <- function(x, ...) {
    UseMethod("howmany", x)
}
```

### Default method:

```r
#' @describeIn howmany Returns the number of unique values in `x`.
#'
#' @param ... `default:` Additional vectors that will be combined with `x` using `c()`.
#'
#' @export
howmany.default <- function(x, ...) { etc
```

### data.frame method

```r
#' @describeIn howmany Returns a dataframe showing the number of unique values in
#'    each column of `x`.
#'
#' @param ... `data.frame:` Column names or positions that are passed to `dplyr::select()`.
#'
#' @export
howmany.data.frame <- function(x, ...) { etc
```

This works fine, but raises an R CMD Check warning:

```
> checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING
  Duplicated \argument entries in documentation object 'howmany':
    '...' '...'
```

How can I document `...` for each of these methods without getting this warning? Thanks!

Comment: Could you separate out to two help files? - `?howmany.default` and `?howmany.data.frame` ? Not sure if that is suggested practice but a similar thing happens for `?seq.default` and `?seq.Date`

Comment: @thelatemail's suggestion is best, but you can also describe both uses in just one of the methods.